# .NET (core) 5.0: Unit testing hangs forever

Tags: .net, .net-core, nunit, mstest, xunit

Pretty simple: no matter what framework I use (xunit, mstest, nunit) they hang forever.

output:

```
Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  testapp -> C:\Users\beene\Documents\coding\csharp\current_projects\testapp\testapp\bin\Debug\net5.0\testapp.dll
  TestProject1 -> C:\Users\beene\Documents\coding\csharp\current_projects\testapp\TestProject1\bin\Debug\net5.0\TestProject1.dll
Test run for C:\Users\beene\Documents\coding\csharp\current_projects\testapp\TestProject1\bin\Debug\net5.0\TestProject1.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 300 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.

Test Run Aborted.
```

Rebuilding the solution yields no warnings or errors of any kind.  Re-running the test produces the same problem.

And it stays there until it times out.  The project is a test project, with a simple "Hello World!" console app and a simple function test to add one to a referenced integer.  That is it.  It's the simplest possible arrangement that reproduces this problem.

My research indicated that these frameworks do, in fact, support .net 5.  I am left only with .NET itself.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  If so I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Anyone who needs more information or would like to run the offending projects can do so.  I published a basic test case project to github that reproduces this issue on both of my computers.  You can find it here:  https://github.com/BeenEncoded/testproject

Comment: What's your OS and are you running using commands or VS/Rider?

Comment: Try deleting your hidden `.vs` folder - does that work?

Comment: Operating System: Windows

Comment: The command is ```dotnet test``` in the solution directory

Comment: Deleting the .vs folder does nothing...

Comment: Try uninstalling & reinstalling .NET 5 SDK?

Comment: After a proper reinstallation of the .NET 5 SDK, nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm facing this problem.. No solutions worked so far... Anyone have another option?

Comment: Now it's working for me, I tried everything but didn't work at the time, the next day it worked without doing anything especial. Obs.: I tried rebooting the system several times, but didn't work on rigth after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using WireGuard or MozillaVPN: it will interfere with how dotnet connects to vstest.console...

Turn your VPN off.

Answer (score 2):

With .Net Core you can do the following command:

```
dotnet test --blame-hang-timeout 10000
```

Once a tests hang more then 10 seconds it will break with a stacktrace